# Do I need GeoServer (or alikes) to provide shape files in a web app?

Tags: django, docker, web-applications, geoserver, geodjango

I am attempting to develop a web app with docker. I have tried to look around and have been confused with the essential components of making one. Please bear me if you see my question naive. This is my first attempt.

I would love to use docker - to make it light weight. I have Postgres/PostGIS as data storage.

The question is - I am not going to provide geotiff files (no raster layers), but only shape files that people can download to make their own desk-top version maps. I am also not going to provide maps (so no need to have open layers and such).  Do I need GeoServer? Would GeoDjango and PostGIS in a docker environment work well enough?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not sure why this got down voted but no you don't. Geodjango and postgis can do the job. I would look into openlayers for displaying it on the page or leaflets. If you were going to do anything with rasters I would suggest Geoserver. I would recommend doing the geodjango tutorial to see if it would meet your needs

Comment: Also these questions are probably better suited for https://gis.stackexchange.com/ you'll get more answers

Comment: Thank you, Taylor. Glad to confirm that I don't need GeoServer. You are right I should ask the question in gis.

Answer (score 1):

Geoserver is (as the name implies) a server to share geospatial data.

Essentially you want to serve shapefiles stored in your application's database so GeoDjango can handle that and you will need to provide the appropriate views to access these data.

You can do the same by deploying a dockerized instance of a Geoserver (there are some ready-made docker images for that) to serve your data, but since you will only serve shapefiles without any processing made on them (and you don't need to server rasters) this may be an overkill.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I should further ask about the benefits of having a Geoserver to serve the data -- does it better support the traffic in production (I don't expect a high level of traffic; I assume there may be a few downloads each day). It would probably help the app expansion in the future, which means again it's not necessary for now.

Comment: @achimneyswallow I haven't used Geoserver with very high loads so I cannot answer that with any measurements. If you are to have low traffic, you will not need geoserver for just a few downloads each day.